# How to calculate relative degree changes in 0 to 360.

Tags: trigonometry

I'm working on a project that measures wind direction and I'm stuck on this what appears to be a simple degree problem.

Example: Lets say I'm a compass (0' .. 360' ) now I'm pointing due north 0' , I want to take readings every minute and now I want to calculate the the minimal difference (relative to last reading) in degrees from the last reading..That is i want to calculate the shortest rotation in degrees that would get me to the current value

```
Assume we start at 0'
Reading 1:  0'   difference=0'
Reading 2:  10'  diff=10' (aka rotate right)
Reading 3:  350  diff=20' (rotate left)
reading 4:  180  diff=170' (rotate left)
```

My issue is that something like
 CurrentDeg- LastDeg =degChange  doesn't work for boundary case for example

```
0 - 350 = -340 (It didnt roate 340 degreess but only 10', looking for minimal degree change - aka Relative offset)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: um, 0-350 is not 340

Comment: @tonyb, are you writing this up in computer code?

Answer (score 2):

break this up into cases:

case1: absolute value of difference in angles is less or equal to 180 degrees. this is the only case you are considering.

case2: absolute value in difference in angles is greater than 180 degrees. If this is the case, then take  360-(difference in angles)

So in psudo-code, it would look something like:

Degree_Change=|current_degree-last_degree| is what you initially calculate. But you have to make sure that it is less than or equal to 180 degrees, so you look at a couple of cases:

> if Degree_Change $\leq$ 180 degrees then Degree_Change=|current_degree-last_degree|

so you do not need to modify it

> if Degree_Change $\ge$ 180 degrees then Degree_Change=360-|current_degree-last_degree|

subtracting by 360 gives you an angle less than 180.

Comment: Looks like tonyb won't be back anytime soon. However, your approach helped me solve my problem in Python. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe can be solved in Python as follows:

```
In [1]: def angle_diff_abs(x, y): 
            if abs(x-y) <= 180: 
                z = abs(x-y)
            else: 
                z = 360 - abs(x-y)          
            return(z)
```

For a selection of tuples:

```
In [2]: tuples = [(30, 90), (90, 30), (20, 340), (340, 20), 
                  (1, 359), (359, 1), (0, 180), (42, 42)]
```

... here is the output:

```
In [3]: for tuplex in tuples: 
            z = angle_diff_abs(tuplex[0], tuplex[1])
            print(f"for {tuplex} is z = {z}")

Out [3]: for (30, 90) is z = 60
         for (90, 30) is z = 60
         for (20, 340) is z = 40
         for (340, 20) is z = 40
         for (1, 359) is z = 2
         for (359, 1) is z = 2
         for (0, 180) is z = 180
         for (42, 42) is z = 0
```

If you also need to determine **the direction of the change** (i.e. clockwise or counterclockwise), this becomes a little more complex:

```
In [4]: def angle_diff_rel(x, y): 
            if abs(x-y) <= 180: 
                if x <= y: 
                    z = abs(x-y)
                else:  # x > y
                    z = y-x
            else: 
                if x < y: 
                    z = abs(x-y) - 360
                else:  # x > y
                    z = 360 - abs(x-y)
            return(z)
```

For the selection of tuples from before, here is the output:

```
In [5]: for tuplex in tuples: 
            z = angle_diff_rel(tuplex[0], tuplex[1])
            print(f"for {tuplex} is z = {z}")

Out [5]: for (30, 90) is z = 60
         for (90, 30) is z = -60
         for (20, 340) is z = -40
         for (340, 20) is z = 40
         for (1, 359) is z = -2
         for (359, 1) is z = 2
         for (0, 180) is z = 180
         for (42, 42) is z = 0
```

Comment: It seems to work, but it's probably too complex. [`(end_angle - start_angle + 180) % 360 - 180`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135864/slice-a-list-based-on-an-index-and-items-behind-it-in-python) should do.

Comment: @Eric Yours is very neat. Personally I find it also very hard to read. I did a quick perfomance comparison: 1) `angle_diff_abs()` with 3.8974 s; `angle_diff_rel()` with 4.0439 s; 3) yours with 4.7557 s (100 executions each for 100,000 tuples). See https://gist.github.com/marianoju/03d12c2b157ec77550054569dcd49f72

Comment: "very hard to read"? Really? It looks like typical modulo arithmetic to me. So `% 360` has to be there. Results should be strictly between `-180`, and `180`, so the two offsets are needed. And that's it, basically. Your methods return 360 for `angle_diff_rel(0, 720)` BTW. It could lead to unexpected bugs depending on the input.

Comment: Results should be strictly between 0 and 180. Input is reading from compass, and no compass will give a reading greater or equal to 360.

Comment: "Results should be strictly between 0 and 180." Why? It's very useful to know the direction of rotation. And your function also returns negative values. Sure, the compass returns values between 0 and 360. But if you add angles, for example, you might get values higher than 360. If you're happy with your function -> goal reached.

Comment: “Results should be strictly between 0 and 180” is implied in examples given by OP. I find the direction useful too.